# Como alinhar texto à direita

Tags: css, css3

Estou com dificuldade em alinhar a tag span id="resultado" a direita.

**Código HTML**

```
<span id="resultado">0</span>
```

**CÓDIGO CSS**

```
#resultado {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Muda de span para div o #resultado

De:

```
<span id="resultado">0</span>
```

Para:

```
<div id="resultado">0</div>
```

E no css deixa assim:

```
#resultado {
    font: bolder, 'Arial';
    font-size: 100px;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Para alinhar um texto a direita usa-se o "text-align: right;" e para alinhar a esquerda se usa "text-align: left;".

Answer (score -3):

Para alinhar um texto usando o CSS, usamos a tag "text-aligner:  ;", recebendo o comando que pode ser "center", "right ou "left", assim alinhando os textos ao centro, a direita e a esquerda da página, respectivamente.

Answer (score -3):

a propriedade a ser utilizada é o "text-align: right;". Caso queira alinhado a esquerda apenas troque o "right" por "left", e caso queira o texto justificado troque por "justify"

Answer (score -3):

Para alinhar um texto a direita basta inserir  a TAG "text-align:right" na configuração do CSS do seu site.